# How do I make my UIImageview respond to a swipe gesture

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uiimageview, swipe

e.g. swap in another UIImage,etc.

Answer (score 2):

A UIImageView is a subclass of UIView. You can add gesture recognizers to any view using [`addGestureRecognizer:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addGestureRecognizer%3a).

Comment: Note this is tagged [iphone-sdk-3.0], gesture recognizers weren't added until 3.2.

Comment: good catch @Anomie - I should read the tags more carefully :)

Answer (score 2):

I see you tagged this [iphone-sdk-3.0]. If you can use SDK 3.2 or later, you can do it easily with `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`. If you must stick with 3.0, you'll have to subclass UIImageView and process `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, `touchesMoved:withEvent:`, `touchesEnded:withEvent:`, and/or `touchesCancelled:withEvent:`.